# Calling a function every 40 second inside a while loop

Tags: c, timer

This code invokes a function for every 40 seconds inside a loop. Since time_t is signed in my linux system, I am doubtful about this condition:

> ```
> if ((time_left <= 0 || time_left > interval))
> ```

Is only checking `(time_left <= 0)` fine? I referred to some websites and they have also added a check for `time_left > interval`. Is this check required?

```
int print_timed_op()
{
    time_t        time_now;
    time_t        time_left;
    time_t        time_next_interval;
    int           interval = 40, hit_count =10; //40 second interval, 10 times
    time_next_interval = time(0) + interval;

   //tight loop
   while (1) {
         sleep(1);
         time_now = time(0);
         time_left = time_next_interval - time_now;
         /* here time_left > interval check required ? */
         if ((time_left <= 0 || time_left > interval)) { 
              call_my_fuc();
              time_next_interval = time(0) + interval;
              time_left = interval;
              hit_count--;
         }

         if(hit_count <= 0)
            break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: I don't want to use a Linux timer system call or any other method to invoke the function periodically.

Comment: `time_left > interval` is only required in `time_t` is unsigned integer, but it is not, so `time_left <= 0` should suffice

Comment: Why can't you just do `while(1){sleep(40); call_my_fuc();}`? (You could insert your `hit_count` check if you want.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check for `time_left > interval` is to deal with clock changes or synchronization.  If your interval is 40 seconds, and someone comes along and updates the system clock to shift it ahead by one hour, you will miss 90 updates if you don't have that check.

You can overcome this in a more precise way by using `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` option.  Then the time will never skip forward or backward, and your function calls will always be evenly spaced.